# How to define a value in bash shell for?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem while using `sh linshi.sh`.

The content of `linshi.sh` is:

```
for i in `cat host-user.txt`
  do
    host = awk '{print $1}' $i
    user = awk '{print $2}' $i
    echo $host
    echo $user
    ssh $hosts pkill -u $user
 done
```

The content of `host-user.txt` is:

```
node1 john
node2 snow
node3 aya
node4 stack
```

But unlucky it doesn't  work, it shows nothing. How to correctly define my variables?

Comment: Run this code through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to correct the errors. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290174) which explains why this `ssh` command will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while read` to read from file:

```
while read -r host user; do
    echo "$host"
    echo "$user"
    ssh "$host" pkill -u "$user" </dev/null
done <host-user.txt
```

`for i in $(cat ...)` - never do that, see [here](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)
`host = ...` - theres is no space before and after `=` when assigning
`= awk ...` - get the output of the command using "$(..)` expression

Comment: it will quit while execute ssh "$host" pkill -u "$user"

Comment: @stack Edited and added `</dev/null` to ssh line. try it now

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems here. The direct answer to your question is `bash` doesn't allow spaces around the assignment operator.

```
# BAD
foo = bar

# GOOD
foo=bar
```

But I need to continue: the `for` line doesn't do what you want. The backticks will expand the output and split by whitespace, so you end up with `for i in node1 john node2 snow node3 aya node4 stack`, which gives you eight iterations with `$i` being one word, not four iterations with `$i` being one line. If you want to iterate over lines, [use `read`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable).

Also, there can't be any spaces inside the value of an assignment, unless the value is quoted. If you write `host=awk '{print $1}' $i`, it will make `host` have the value `awk`, then launch a subshell and try to run the program `{print $1}` with the parameter that is the value of `i` - not what you meant. But you actually probably meant that you want to run `awk`, and here you'd use the backtick quotes, or even better `$(...)` because it allows nesting and is clearer to read.

Comment: I have tested while read as Kamil Cuk said. But it would be stopped while running ssh command

Comment: I did not think I need to repeat the warning from arco444. I answered your question - how to correctly define your variables; your `ssh` problem is unrelated.